# Wrong computation of average per row

Tags: r, row

I have the following s dataframe:

```
s
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
1  0  8  7 15  9 10  9  9
2  8  0  8 16 12 12 12 12
3  7  8  0 15 11 10 10  8
4 15 16 15  0 17 15 17 15
5  9 12 11 17  0 11 10 12
6 10 12 10 15 11  0 11  8
7  9 12 10 17 10 11  0 13
8  9 12  8 15 12  8 13  0

class (s)
# [1] "data.frame"
class (s[1,1])
# [1] "numeric"
```

I add a new column in order to calculate the average per row:

```
s$means<-data.frame(Means=rowMeans(s[,-1]))
```

Here is the calculated average:

```
s
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8     Means
1  0  8  7 15  9 10  9  9  9.571429
2  8  0  8 16 12 12 12 12 10.285714
3  7  8  0 15 11 10 10  8  8.857143
4 15 16 15  0 17 15 17 15 13.571429
5  9 12 11 17  0 11 10 12 10.428571
6 10 12 10 15 11  0 11  8  9.571429
7  9 12 10 17 10 11  0 13 10.428571
8  9 12  8 15 12  8 13  0  9.714286
```

However the calculation is wrong.
The right averages per row are as followed:

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  Average
1   0   8   7   15  9   10  9   9   8.375
2   8   0   8   16  12  12  12  12  10
3   7   8   0   15  11  10  10  8   8.625
4   15  16  15  0   17  15  17  15  13.75
5   9   12  11  17  0   11  10  12  10.25
6   10  12  10  15  11  0   11  8   9.625
7   9   12  10  17  10  11  0   13  10.25
8   9   12  8   15  12  8   13  0   9.625
```

Why is the calculation wrong and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Just do `rowMeans(s)`

Comment: To answer your question on why the calculation is wrong: It is because you are excluding the values in the first column `V1` from the calculation of the average by using `s[, -1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
 s$Average <- rowMeans(s)
```

to get the required output

```
s
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 Average
#1  0  8  7 15  9 10  9  9   8.375
#2  8  0  8 16 12 12 12 12  10.000
#3  7  8  0 15 11 10 10  8   8.625
#4 15 16 15  0 17 15 17 15  13.750
#5  9 12 11 17  0 11 10 12  10.250
#6 10 12 10 15 11  0 11  8   9.625
#7  9 12 10 17 10 11  0 13  10.250
#8  9 12  8 15 12  8 13  0   9.625
```